# Tags section of Markdown help shows "siteName"

Tags: bug, status-completed, editing-help

[The tags section of the Markdown help](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/markdown#tags) reads in part:

> To talk about a tag on siteName, [like-this](/questions/tagged/like-this), use

It seems like `siteName` was intended to be replaced with the name of the site in question, but it isn't. Perhaps it should be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed with build rev 2013.12.30.1811 on meta and 2013.12.30.1270 on sites.